# Java Heap Space Error while sending data more than 12 MB over SOAP using Webservices

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am trying to send an object of 15 MB from Flex to Java using webservice. My server is tomcat. I have set memory both in Eclipse and tomcat as `-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`
But I am getting this error:-

```
ERROR org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver  - Java heap space
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.toString
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you tell what are you doing when this happens? It seems that you are doing something with MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing `-Xmx1024m` to for example `-Xmx2048m`. Your MaxPermSize is probably way too large it does not help when heap runs out, try `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`.

Comment: +1 for the comment about permgen.  (Smells of voodoo tuning to me ... "increase permgen size and sacrifice a chicken at midnight" :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending data over chunks -

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-unbuffered-chunk-encoded-post-re.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ChunkedInputStream.html